# How to retrieve ACLs from Blob Container

Tags: .net, azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake-gen2

I am using Azure storage .NET SDK for managing Data lake Gen2 storage ACLs. It is working fine for retrieving ACLs from files and directories inside Blob container, but it throws an error for the container itself.

To better illustrate the problem here are my blob containers, the one I am accessing is called `data`:

[image: This is my storage account]

When I am retrieving ACLs from, for example, `data/MyFolder2` path, the method works fine, but not if I try with `data` path.

Error that is being thrown:

> Service request failed.\r\nStatus: 400 (Value for one of the query
> parameters specified in the request URI is
> invalid.)\r\n\r\nHeaders:\r\nServer:
> Windows-Azure-HDFS/1.0,Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\r\nx-ms-request-id:
> 89561112-8b6877000000\r\nDate: Wed, 29 Jun 2022
> 16:42:47 GMT\r\n

This my code:

```
...
string container = "data";
string folderPath = "MyFolder2";
DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(mySASconnectionString);
DataLakeDirectoryClient dirClient = dataLakeClient.GetFileSystemClient(container).GetDirectoryClient(directoryPath);
Azure.Response<PathAccessControl> accessControlReponse = dirClient.GetAccessControl();
...
```

I have all permissions required since I am connecting as storage account owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to retrieve ACls from Blob container (root directory) is to initialize client as shown below:

```
...
string container = "data";
DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeClient = new DataLakeServiceClient(mySASconnectionString);
DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient = dataLakeClient.GetFileSystemClient(container);
DataLakePathClient client = new DataLakePathClient(fileSystemClient, "/");
Azure.Response<PathAccessControl> accessControlReponse = client.GetAccessControl();
...
```

The problem was while looping from target directory to its root, method `DataLakePathClient.GetParentDirectoryClient()` was returning URI of the root path with the missing '/' which was causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to check and validate if your storage account firewall is enabled or not?

If not, Go to **storage account** ->**Networking** ->**check to allow access to all networks**.

Sometimes you get an error if you have metadata file, metadata should not contain special characters or additional space starting of the value and end of the value.

**Reference:**

[End-to-end troubleshooting using Azure Storage metrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/storage/common/storage-e2e-troubleshooting)

[Monitor, diagnose, and troubleshoot Microsoft Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-monitoring-diagnosing-troubleshooting?tabs=dotnet)

Comment: It allows access to all networks but the method still throws an error